# Работа со связаным списком

Tags: c, список, строки

Здравствуйте!
Во время выполнения задания связаного ссо связаными списками столкнулся с проблемой, не считает результат. Код компилируется. Задание состоит в том, что есть номер, пункт направления и цена билета, надо вычислить среднюю стоимость билетов. Не выводит среднюю стоимость, я так понимаю, что-то упустил. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку, голова совсем не варит.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vcl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
struct spis{
        int nom;
        char pun[50];
        float var;
        struct spis* ptr;
};
char bufCur[250];
char* Cur(const char* text)
{CharToOem(text,bufCur);
return bufCur;
}
int main()
{
        srand(time(NULL));
        int nom,n ,i;
        char pun[50];
        float var,sum=0, ser_var;
        struct spis* newptr;
        struct spis* startptr;
        struct spis* endptr;
        startptr=NULL;
        printf(Cur("Кiлькiсть вузлів:"));
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            newptr=(spis*) malloc(sizeof(spis));
            if(newptr!=NULL){
                    newptr->nom=i+1;
                    printf(Cur("\n\nНомер рейса: %d"), newptr->nom);
                    printf(Cur("\nВведіть напрям: "));
                    scanf("%s", &newptr->pun);
                    newptr->var=rand()%10000*0.1;
                    printf(Cur("\nВартiсть: %3.1f"), newptr->var);
                    newptr->ptr=startptr;
                    startptr=newptr;
            }
    }
    endptr=newptr;
    newptr=endptr;

    while(newptr!=NULL){
    sum+=newptr->var;
    }
    newptr->ptr;

    ser_var=sum/n;
    printf(Cur("Середня вартість проїзду: %f"), ser_var);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идее должно быть так:

`...
newptr=startptr;`

while(newptr!=NULL){
   sum+=newptr->var;
   newptr = newptr -> ptr;
}
...

Comment: а куда в какой рядок внести Вашу первую поправку?

Comment: сразу извиняюсь. если вопрос глупый

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, строка                               newptr->ptr;, после цикла подсчета сумы лишняя?

Comment: и все работает)

Comment: в конце. я вижу еще одну проблему в том что startptr постоянно меняется вместо того чтобы всегда указывать на начало списка.

Comment: где именно?  скажите пожалуйста?

Comment: в первом цикле?

Comment: да, у тебя должен меняться endptr

Comment: просто поменять последнюю строчку цикла?

Comment: все уже разобрался, спасибо еще раз